# What would happen to Ben Newman if he didn’t pay his costs order by December?

Tags: england-and-wales, costs, injunctions

Ben Newman is a UK animal rights activist who interferes with horse races by running onto the course to delay the races. [He was criminially convicted in early July 2023 and given a fine and community service for this after pleading guilty, as Surry Police reported.](https://www.surrey.police.uk/news/surrey/news/2023/07/man-who-ran-on-the-racetrack-during-epsom-derby-sentenced/).

One of the tracks he interfered at also had an injunction against him. I'm assuming it was an injunction ordering him to stay away. Apparently, he broke it. The company subsequently sued him in civil court and won 10k UKP in costs. Apparently, the judgment was for [contempt of court and delivered in early October, as the BBC reports.](https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cyx1p2lzeyqo)

Now he's trying to raise money to pay that. According to [his crowd-funding page](https://chuffed.org/project/jockey-club-vs-ben-newman-costs), he must settle this order by December.

Why might such a deadline have been set, and what could be the repercussions of failing to meet it?

Comment: I overworked the information after you clarified it - as rewritten, this tells the story - including your interpretation from the news and other sources - leading to the actually very good question: why is the timeframe so long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why might such a deadline have been set

Standard terms are 14 days after the order for costs  - or another date at the court's discretion. Given the non-trivial amount the court may have used that discretion in giving him the extra time.

I don't expect it will come to it, given he'll likely gift enough through gofundme or pay it using a Director's Loan or similar from his company.

He's not got the best form for doing what the court tells him to though so if he **doesn't** pay there's various options the plaintiff can use to recoup the money:

**Goods owned (warrant of control)**

Court enforcement agents (aka Bailiffs in common parlance) will be despatched to seize money/goods from the defendant to sell at auction. They will only seize goods if they are worth enough to pay the warrant - and there's various restrictions on what they are allowed to take.

**Wages or salary (attachment of earnings order)**

Exactly what it says on the tin - they'll deduct an amount from each wage the defendant receives until the debt is settled. This is obviously only applicable where the defendant is employed - self employed doesn't count but if he pays himself through PAYE then it can be garnished.

**Savings (third-party debt order)**

If they've actually *got* the money but are refusing to pay it a third-party debt order can be used against a bank account where the money is. This prevents them from withdrawing money and then the court will decide whether to make a "final order" or not - in the event that they do so the third party (i.e. the bank) will pay the money to the plaintiff directly.

**Assets (charging order)**

If the debtor has property (be it physical property such as a house or financial instruments like stocks, shares or funds) a "charge" can be placed on them - so that if/when they sell the property they can only do so if they pay the debt in the process. This doesn't *compel* them to sell the property - although a separate "order for sale" could then be pursued.

In this particular case I'm not sure whether failure to pay court-ordered costs would be sufficient to trigger the suspended jail sentence Mr Newman has for contempt of court or not.

Comment: Which company are you referring to in the context of a possible director’s loan?

Comment: The [company formerly known as Animal Rebellion](https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/12064173)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149205/discussion-on-answer-by-motosubatsu-what-would-happen-to-ben-newman-if-he-didnt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.